# Parse fetching User inside of hook not working

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server

i am using this

```
var USER = Parse.Object.extend("_User");
var query = new Parse.Query(USER);
query.get(request.user.id, {
success: function(results) {
  console.log(results);
  // results has the list of users with a hometown team with a winning record
},
error : function(error){
  console.error(error);
}
```

to fetch the user making the request. (In this case it's a after save hook)

For any reason "results" just containing:
ParseObjectSubclass { className: '_User', _objCount: 2, id: 'zW3o9c2wbY' }

But i need access to other fields of this user - how can i do so?

Best, Nico

Answer (score 0):

[see query documentation](https://parseplatform.github.io/Parse-SDK-JS/api/classes/Parse.Query.html#methods_include) the include method is what you are looking for.

Fyi, here's how I would write it:

```
new Parse.Query(Parse.User)
 .include('ptrFieldIWantReturned')
  // master key shouldn't be needed, but I can't be sure of your config.
 .get(request.user.id, { useMasterKey: true }) 
 .then(
   user => console.log('got: ' + user.id),
   error => console.error('uh-oh: ' + error.message)
  );
```